# Как сравнить массив объектов с массивом по условию?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
arr1: [ 
 {id:2, title:'значение 1'},
 {id:3, title:'значение 2'},
 {id:5, title:'значение 3'},
 {id:7, title:'значение 4'},
 {id:8, title:'значение 5'},
],
arr2: [2,5]
```

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста как сравнить эти 2 массива и результат записать в новый массив.
Условие сравнивания: id объекта массива cat должно быть одинаковым с числом из второго массива.
Проще говоря вот так:

```
result: [
 {id:2, title:'значение 1'},
 {id:5, title:'значение 3'},
]
```

написал вот что:

```
result = arr1.filter((el) => arr2.includes(el.id))
```

устраивает, но не соблюдается очередь, получается первое залетает то что выше в arr1, хотелось бы чтобы сначала в массив попало совпадение с 2, а потом с 5. например если взять массив

```
arr2: [5,2],
```

здесь как раз наблюдается ошибка, то есть так как id2 выше по массиву сначала отправляется она, а не 5. Подскажите как решить пожалуйста.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: нашел еще такой вариант, пусть останется, может кому пригодиться  result = arr2.map((id) => arr1.find((el) => el.id === id))

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1):

Элементарная задача на 2 строки кода. Перебрать массив `arr2` и на каждой итерации обходить `arr1` в поисках нужного `id`. Потом фильтровать результат, оставляя только найденные элементы.

Что вам советуют - непонятно.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 2, title: 'значение 1' },
  { id: 3, title: 'значение 2' },
  { id: 5, title: 'значение 3' },
  { id: 7, title: 'значение 4' },
  { id: 8, title: 'значение 5' },
];

const arr2 = [5, 2];

const res = arr2
  .map((id) => arr1.find((i) => i.id === id))
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(res); // [{ id: 5, title: "..." }, { id: 2, title: "..." }]
```

Хотя это не оптимальный с точки зрения алгоритмической сложности алгоритм, но пока вы работаете с массивами длинной менее 10000 элементов - проблем возникнуть не должно. Тут тот случай, когда читаемость и ясность перевешивают незначительные объективные теоретические показатели скорости.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [ 
  {id:2, title:'значение 1'},
  {id:3, title:'значение 2'},
  {id:5, title:'значение 3'},
  {id:7, title:'значение 4'},
  {id:8, title:'значение 5'},
]

var ids = [2,5]

console.log(ids.map(id => data.find(x => x.id == id)))
```

Но вообще-то лучше вместо массива использовать словарь:

```js
var data = { 
  2: {id:2, title:'значение 1'},
  3: {id:3, title:'значение 2'},
  5: {id:5, title:'значение 3'},
  7: {id:7, title:'значение 4'},
  8: {id:8, title:'значение 5'},
}

var ids = [2, 5]

console.log(ids.map(id => data[id]))
```

Comment: Если в массиве с запросом будет несуществующий id, то в результат падает undefined

Comment: @novvember, а он там может быть? В любом случае, решается добавлением `.filter(Boolean)`.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще вариант, что сначала применить фильтр, как у вас, а потом сделать сортировку, как в массиве с запросом:

```js
const arr1 = [ 
 {id:2, title:'значение 1'},
 {id:3, title:'значение 2'},
 {id:5, title:'значение 3'},
 {id:7, title:'значение 4'},
 {id:8, title:'значение 5'},
];
const arr2 = [5, 2]

function getResult(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1
    .filter(({id}) => arr2.includes(id))
    .sort((a, b) => arr2.indexOf(a.id) - arr2.indexOf(b.id));
}

console.log(getResult(arr1, arr2));
```